# Java Datastructure linking two unique keys

Tags: java, hashmap

I hava currently have a hashmap where a token is mapped to a username (don't know if this is gramatically correct, the token is the key). Both the tokens and the usernames are unique. However for some operations I need to be able to access the token through the username. I thought about two solutions: The obvious one of just going through all the usernames. And using a second hashmap to map the username to the token.

But is there a better one (like a datastructure which mapps two unique keys)?